# Point homepage of onlineshop to different server then rest of the shop

Tags: web, server, dns

I have an onlineshop running on Server A. Now I created a landingpage with WordPress on Server B. My problem: I want the homepage (index page) of the shop to be the landingpage from Server B. How can I do that in the best way?

Example how it should be:
www.shop.com (homepage, index, from server B)
www.shop.com/product1 (normal content from server A)

I thought about iFrames, but they are not good for SEO and also it doesn't look that good. I thought about just DNS changes, but that's obviously not possible. I am really lost at the moment.

Comment: Why don't you try to create a subdomian for server B something like store.shop.com pointing to server B via CNAME

Comment: Hi, you mean like putting the shop on the subdomain like store.shop.com (Server A) and point the real main page shop.com to Server B? This is actually a pretty good idea. Is there any other option still?

Comment: You can also use Nginx to redirect to specific upstream server (server A or B) based on the URL. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220678/how-to-redirect-to-specific-upstream-servers-based-on-request-url-in-nginx