# How to listen to POST requests made to an already listening server using express with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, http, go

I created a local server on the 8080 port using go. This server already has the 'listening' status, and I cannot access to it using app.listen(8080) because the server is already in this status.
This previously golang code is doing some POST requests that I would like to see on the nodeJS script using express. Currently, no requests are visible on my side.

So this is my code:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
})

setInterval(function() {
}, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

I added the setInterval to make the script "wait" in substitution to the app.listen, but I'm not sure if it would cause any issue though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server binds to a port that it runs on. This means, on any given machine, one server can only bind itself to one port. Now, when the go server is already running on port 8080, your node server cannot use that port. You'll have to use a different port and then you'll have to request the new server with a new port.

You can do the following:
Go server works on 8080, http://localhost:8080 -> Go server
Node server works on 8000, http://localhost:8000 -> Node server

If you want to wrap this all under a single port, you'll need an http server (like Nginx) and then define reverser proxy and routing rules there. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220678/how-to-redirect-to-specific-upstream-servers-based-on-request-url-in-nginx/27240080).

Comment: Thank you very very much, it worked like a charm !